# Wrong output by Multithreading in WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

When I try the Code to execute, the result is not like I wait it.

I try in **first Test** a range of number from 1 to max = 200000 in parallel  using WebFlux(Flux) in File to write them.

And the **second Test**, I try to check the first Test, but I find not all numbers were streamed(covered), und when the first Test was finish, the second test should wait, I don't know why?

The result after waiting is **Scanning in numbers: [19.601], and the max is: [19.978]**

But without waiting, **Scanning in numbers: [0], and the max is: [0]**

Can anyone pleas explain, why the range of number it was not covered, and why I should wait in the next Test, and why the statement after paralleling were executed before the range was finish?

```
package loadtest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class LoadTest {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/test-parallel.txt";

    private final int max = 20000;


    @Test
    public void test01_WriteParallel() throws Exception {

        Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(FILE_NAME));

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME);

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        // get the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine
        int numberOfProcessors = runtime.availableProcessors();

        System.out.println("Number of processors available to this JVM: " + numberOfProcessors);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Flux.range(1, max)
            .parallel(numberOfProcessors)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .subscribe(i -> printWriter.printf(String.format("%s%n", i)));


        System.out.println(String.format("It was ended in: %sms", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));


    }

    @Test
    public void test02_GetMaxOfRange() throws InterruptedException{

       Thread.sleep(15000);
        final List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    integers.add(Integer.valueOf(line));
                }

            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int max = integers.parallelStream()
                          .mapToInt(t -> t)
                          .max().orElse(0);

        System.out.println(String.format("Scanning in numbers: [%,d], and the max is: [%,d]", integers.size(), max));

    }


}
```

Comment: Your Flux is asynchronous, the first test case finishes earlier than the actual processing does. Instead of `subscribe` you can try `blockLast` to ensure the processing is finished before starting the next test case. (Although, it's usually not a good idea to have dependency between test cases. )

Comment: Thx for your comment,

I have wrote the second Test only for checking, because the next statement after Flux it will be executed, 

For **blockLast()** it will not execute the parallel.

Comment: Your Flux will be parallel even with blockLast. But I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: you're right, I  have this wrote and it works.
`Flux.range(1, max)
        .parallel(numberOfProcessors)
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .doOnNext(i ->  printWriter.printf(String.format("%s%n", i))))
        .sequential()
        .blockLast();
`